# What is this component on a satellite TV STB?

Tags: identification

can you please help identify this component and tell what is it for?

Component:
[image]
[Component image](https://pasteboard.co/J12xj8g.jpg)

It is mounted on a satellite tv STB.

Comment: Which component are you referring to, the connector?

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me what name it is referred by?

Comment: That is a connector.  A 68-pin ribbon cable attaches there.

Comment: Any ideas on why it may be there on an STB pcb? Possible applications?

Comment: These are often used to program the unit or update its firmware.

Comment: It could also be used for an accessory, such as an external hard-drive (like for a DVR).  SCSI drives often use 68 pin connectors, although usually a different shape.

Comment: Isn't that the CI slot connector for attaching the module for pay TV cards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a PCMCIA connector, which is ordinarily used for CableCard on cable STBs. I've not seen one on a satellite box however (I'm in the US - DirecTV and Echostar boxes don't use PCMCIA, so that's why I haven't seen one.)

What's the model of the box? (you answered.)

EDIT: A cursory search for this box doesn't show the PCMCIA slot specifically. That said, sometimes in STBs the PCMCIA card holds the conditional access hardware, which itself has an ISO7816 card inserted for the keying material. I suppose this is an optional interface on this box so if it needs to support a conditional access scheme that the internal chip doesn't support, the provider can use the external type instead.

The way these schemes work is that they take the encrypted tuner feed and circulate it through the card, where it is decrypted, then re-encrypted using local keys supplied by the ISO card, then sent back to the system chip where it is decrypted once more and finally decoded for presentation.

This way, the data are never 'in the clear' except inside the system chip where it's not visible to prying.

Comment: It is Videocon d2h HD 6666